# How to create pass with custom design?

Tags: ios, json, user-interface, passbook, passkit

Have a pass with Store Card style. How can I add 2nd row with data and change the label position (label should be below the value)? When I add second item in secondaryFields array it inserts the item in the 2nd column, the same row. Thanks.

Image as example:

[image]

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/20785/beginning-passbook-in-ios-6-part-22 ?

Comment: Ray uses generic pass style for this http://prntscr.com/4pu1v3

Comment: it's unappropriate for me because I need pass image as on picture above, not square

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look here "Pass Style Sets the Overall Visual Appearance":

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW45

It gives an overview of what fields are allowed on the different pass types.

To achieve what you describe you want to make the pass a generic pass and specify both secondary and auxiliary fields.

To switch the label to be below the data, you need to flip the values when specifying them, so set label ="Gold" and the value="Level". However it will still have the same formatting (the top one will still be smaller text)